# Is there a way that I can make my lines be by country in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really have two questions.  Does anyone know how to make my lines connect by country? At the moment, they are just connecting all the dots.  Also does anyone know how to change my legend so that instead of five increasing size dots, there will be just three?

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(gapminder) +
  geom_point(aes(year, gdpPercap, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  geom_line(aes(year, gdpPercap, color = continent)) +
  facet_wrap(~ continent, nrow = 1) +
  scale_size_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "", 
                                                     scale = .00001)) +
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what you mean connect by country?

Comment: yes, thats what I mean

Comment: Try with adding `group = country` to geom_line to override the default grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Breaks take a while to get right but you can force it

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(gapminder) +
  geom_point(aes(year, gdpPercap, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  geom_line(aes(year, gdpPercap, color = continent,group = country)) +
  facet_wrap(~ continent, nrow = 1) +
  scale_size_binned(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "", 
                                                     scale = .00001),n.breaks   = 3,nice.breaks = F) +
  
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Another option is to try a transformation that gets you your desired number of breaks

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(gapminder) +
  geom_point(aes(year, gdpPercap, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  geom_line(aes(year, gdpPercap, color = continent,group = country)) +
  facet_wrap(~ continent, nrow = 1) +
  scale_size(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "",scale = .00001),trans = "log") +
  
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```